# Delete rows using .Range.Find() method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find each cell that contains the following value "# Results" and if the cell to the right is == 0 then delete the entire row as well as the row below.

However, since I am deleting rows, the .Range.Find method gets buggy and fails to find the next occurence after the first deletion. How can I make this code work?

Here is the code:

```
sub KillEmptyResults()

Dim sRows As Range
Dim X As Range

Set X = Nothing
SearchStr = Chr(35) & " Results"
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set X = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not X Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAddress = X.address
        Do
            'Transform anchor row to entire range to delete
            If X.Offset(0, 1).Value = "0" Then
                Set sRow = Rows(X.Row).EntireRow
                Set sRows = sRow.Resize(sRow.Rows.Count + 1, sRow.Columns.Count)
                sRows.Delete
            End If
            Set X = .FindNext(X)
        Loop While Not X Is Nothing And X.address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: `Union` found cells, then delete at once after the `Loop`

Comment: I think you should loop from `Set X = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)` until X is nothing, and add a break point if it returns to first coincidence.

Comment: Btw, another method would be to simply `AutoFilter` your `UsedRange`. You would maybe find that less confusing? It seems you interested in the same columns containing your criteria and your offset value

Comment: @JvdV - how would you delete the row underneath with AF?

Comment: @SJR, I would set a `Range` object using `SpecialCells(12)` and then loop through the `Areas/Cells` using a simple `Resize`. It's just an option for OP if it would be easier to understand. Anyways, I would still go with my first comment =)

Comment: @JvdV - ok I see now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the problem is that if you are deleting rows as you go you will change the address of previously found cells, so store the relevant ranges as you go, and do the deleting at the end:

```
Sub KillEmptyResults()

Dim sRows As Range
Dim X As Range, sFirstAddress As String, SearchStr As String, rDelete As Range

SearchStr = Chr(35) & " Results"

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set X = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not X Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = X.Address
            Do
                'Transform anchor row to entire range to delete
                If X.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Then
                    If rDelete Is Nothing Then 'establish range to be deleted
                        Set rDelete = X.Resize(2).EntireRow
                    Else
                        Set rDelete = Union(rDelete, X.Resize(2).EntireRow)
                    End If
                End If
                Set X = .FindNext(X)
            Loop While X.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
End With

If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Would `UsedRange` work if there are empty rows? Saying that, OP has accepted the answer so I'm presuming that is not the case

Comment: @Zac - yes it should do (`currentregion` would fail) although it's not generally recommended.

Comment: Interesting. I thought `UsedRange` had a problem with empty rows but worked with non-contiguous range. I have a macro running but will give it a go once it's done.. That's the new thing for the day for me :)

Comment: @Zac - by all means give it a test but `usedrange` is based on the last cell used and can be a problem as could still include empty cells previously containing something (if document unsaved).

Comment: You are wright. That's the behaviour i just noticed. I stayed clear of `UsedRange` for the sole purpose that I thought it stopped at the first empty row. I would use it in the future if the scenario requires it. Thanks